# Создание новой вкладки(jTabbedPane) java Swing GUI в Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Нужно, что бы по нажатию на кнопку в окне приложения открывалась вторая вкладка с определенными данными.

Рассматриваю такие варианты реализации:

1. При нажатии на кнопку создавать новую вкладку с нужной информацией.
2. При нажатии на кнопку выводить на вторую вкладку нужную информацию и переключаться на нее в приложении.

Но как это сделать, с учетом того что пишу программу в Netbeans и интерфейс сделан в графическом редакторе?

Comment: А если подготовить заранее вкладку, сделать её не видимой, а при нажатии на кнопку делать её видимой и переходить на неё? Или надо именно создавать её в runtime?